# Angular Routerlink doesn't work

Tags: angular, routes

I'm just getting a grip on the Angular RouterModule, please bear with me.

I've setup an app-component with buttons that let the user login and register. But Angular returns a 404 when the link is clicked; I can't understand why, I've followed the example.

Would any-one have any idea as to where I may find the issue?

I have 2 important modules:

1. the user-module which contains the authentication service, as well
   as login/register/... components
2. the entry-module which contains the actual application

// app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './page-not-found/page-not-found.component';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';    
import { UserModule } from './user/user.module';
import { AuthenticationService } from './user/authentication.service';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing/app-routing.module';
import { EntryModule } from './entry/entry.module.ts';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'entries', component: EntryListComponent },
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'entries', pathMatch: 'full'}, // empty
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent} // catch-all
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    PageNotFoundComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    UserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [
    AuthenticationService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

// app.component.html (excerpt)

```
  <button *ngIf='!(currentUser | async) else ng-hide'class="ui button" title="Login">
    <a class="item" routerLinkActive='active' routerLink="/login">
      <i class="large black user icon"></i>
    </a>
  </button>
  <button *ngIf='!(currentUser | async) else ng-hide' class="ui button" title="Register">
    <a class="item" routerLinkActive='active' routerLink="/register">
      <i class="large black user plus icon"></i>
    </a>
```

// app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from '../page-not-found/page-not-found.component';
import { SelectivePreloadStrategy } from './SelectivePreloadStrategy';
import { AuthGuardService } from '../user/auth-guard.service';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'entry',
    canActivate: [ AuthGuardService ],
    loadChildren: 'app/entry/entry.module#EntryModule' // <<< THIS IS IMPORTANT
  },
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'entry', pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent}
];


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { preloadingStrategy: SelectivePreloadStrategy })
  ],
  declarations: [],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

I'm not quite sure if the problem lies in any of those files, but the Github repo can be found [here](https://github.com/Pieter-JanVanDamme/Cartabell).

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: Where's your routing config for login or register?

Comment: You mean in app-routing.module.ts? There isn't any, the example I'm following doesn't either. Or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: @HarryNinh is asking where your `login` and `register` routes are. You call for them in the html file by doing `routerLink="/register"` and `routerLink="/login"` but you never add them in the module

Comment: They are in the UserModule, so relative to app.component.html that's ./user/login/login.component.ts and ./user/register/register.component.ts